# R. Excel read change column types

Tags: r

I am reading in an excel file and all the columns are showing  when I do a head(xxx). I was able to do the following to rename some of the columns
names(xxx) [2] <- NameAsTxt
names(xxx) [5] <- Numbers
But I then need to do a summarise and sum, after doing a group by. My code is failing, even though it looks right. I believe that I need to change the second Numbers column to  and then my sum should work, or at least I think that is what will happen.

```
gal_20 <- read_excel("xxx.xlsx")
head(gal_20)
names(gal_20)[2] <-"Name"
names(gal_20)[5] <-"Number"
gal_20_votes <- select(gal_20, Name, Number)%>%
  group_by(Name)##%>%
##summarise(gal_20_votes, votes = sum(Number))
  
gal_20_votes
```

So I changed the names of column 2 and 5, but they come up as chr and I believe that if they were dbl my sum which I have commented out, would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it working. I used mutate to create Number as numeric

```
mutate(Number = as.numeric(Number))
```